# Jquery function to set active nav tab using url is selecting more than it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, navigation

I have a Jquery function which I use to set the 'active' class on my nav anchors, it uses the URL to do so. The function works for the most part but the problem is that when tab 1 is active it's also setting tabs 10, 11 and 12 as active too.

The code below is what I'm using and it's correctly outputting the `page` in the console.log, it also works as it should for all other links except Item 1 as seen in the screenshot.

[image: Nav showing active on 1, 10, 11 and 12]

```
$(function(){
   var url = window.location.href;
   var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );
   $('.nav-item a[href*="'+page+'"]').addClass('active');
   console.log(page);
 });
```

---

The nav is fairly large so I'll share a condensed version, just keep in mind that middle ul actually contains a total of 12 Items and each item shares the url

`article.php?contentID=`

After the `=` comes the item number from 1 to 12.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <ul class="navbar-nav" >
    <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="articles.php">Twist</a></li>
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="article.php?contentID=1">Item 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="commentary.php">Commentary</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="logLink" class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Log out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Any help would be appreciated and I'm pretty sure it's something obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks in advance.

Twist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the '[attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)' selector which selects any that have the given sub-string "article.php?contentID=1".
So this matches all of the following
"**article.php?contentID=1**",
"**article.php?contentID=1**0",
"**article.php?contentID=1**1",
"**article.php?contentID=1**2", and
"some_**article.php?contentID=1**whatever"

Just remove the `*`
`'.nav-item a[href="'+page+'"]'`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... The key was to have `href$="='+page+'"` so that the statement which adds the `active` class becomes:

> $('.nav-item a[href$="=' + page + '"]').addClass('active');

Working **snippet** below - change the hardcoded value of page to test yourself:

```js
$(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var page = 1 //url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );
  $('.nav-item a[href$="=' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
  console.log('looking for page#:', page);
});
```

```css
a.nav-link.active {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <h2>Nav</h2>
  <p>Basic horizontal menu:</p>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#article.php?contentID=1">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#article.php?contentID=2">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#article.php?contentID=10">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#article.php?contentID=11">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#article.php?contentID=21">Link</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works at resolving the 1 making 10, 11 and 12 active but it locks the active on the hard coded page number of `var page = 2;//url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1 ); ` When removing the hard coded number and the commented part, like so,  'var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );'   no items show active